# Execute native code from within Cordova without a plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I have this requirements:

- I have a WebView build with Cordova.
- In the webpage I have to include a third party script
- I need to install a third party SDK in my App
- The third party script has to execute some methods of the SDK

**How can the third party providing the script achieve this?**

I started looking at this cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-cdp-nativebridge` (https://github.com/sony/cordova-plugin-cdp-nativebridge) that I could use as light mapping of their calls to the native methods but my concern is that it's not maintained.

Could the third party providing us the script use [NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript) to execute native code directly from their Javascript script?

Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you have a native android app with embedded Cordova WebView that loads the third party script? Is this third party script is just a simple web app, wondering why you prefer Cordova WebView over the default Android WebView.

Comment: @Manoj The third party script is not a web app. It's a script injected in our web app running inside the Cordova WebView. We cannot use default Android WebView as per given requirements. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but I'm still trying to understand what does the script do? Can you give us some example, why it would need native api access.